# Fit Latex Table to Page

Tags: tables

I have a table in the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt
DIVcalc,                            % führt die Satzspiegelberechnung neu aus
twoside                     % einseitiges Layout
twocolumn,                      % zweispaltiger Satz
openany,                            % Kapitel können auch auf linken Seiten beginnen
headsepline,                    % Trennline zum Seitenkopf  
footsepline,                    % Trennline zum Seitenfuß
chapterprefix,              % vor Kapitelüberschrift wird "Kapitel Nummer" gesetzt
appendixprefix,             % Anhang wird "Anhang" vor die Überschrift gesetzt 
normalheadings,          % Überschriften etwas kleiner (smallheadings)
idxtotoc,                       % Index im Inhaltsverzeichnis
liststotoc,                 % Abb.- und Tab.verzeichnis im Inhalt
bibtotoc,
bibtotoc
]
{scrbook}


\pagestyle{headings}    % lebender Kolumnentitel  

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}   %%Für Tabellenformatierung
\usepackage{float} % unterdrückt, dass Bilder ins falsche Kapitel getan werden (mit eckiger Klammer mit [H])
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}%Seitenlayout definieren
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{graphicx} %%Zum Laden von Grafiken
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\setuptoc{toc}{numbered}


\begin{document}

\title{Bachelor}
\author{me}

\maketitle

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents            % Inhaltsverzeichnis

\mainmatter                     % Hauptteil

\begin{table}
    \caption{Eigenschaften des Raspberry Pi}
    \label{tab:EigenschaftendesRaspberryPitabelle}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{\uline{Eigenschaften}}}            &         \textbf{\uline{Modell A}}  & \textbf{\uline{Modell A+}} &         \textbf{\uline{Modell B}} & \textbf{\uline{Modell B+}} & \textbf{\uline{Raspberry Pi 2 Model B}} \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Gesamtgrösse (in mm)} & Länge  & 93        & 70,4        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{93}                         \\ \cline{2-10} 
                                                                            & Breite & 63,5      & 57,2        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{63,5}                       \\ \cline{2-10} 
                                                                            & Höhe   & 17        & 12          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{20}                         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{SoC}                      & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Broadcom BCM2835}         & Broadcom BCM2836       \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{CPU}                  & Typ    & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{ARM1176JZF-S}             & ARM Cortex-A7          \\ \cline{2-10} 
                                                                            & Kern   & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{1}                        & 4                      \\ \cline{2-10} 
                                                                            & Takt   & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{700 MHz}                  & 900 MHz                \\ \cline{2-10} 
                                                                            & Architektur & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{ARMv6}               & ARMv7                  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Arbeitsspeicher}          & 256 MB & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{512 MB}          & 1024 MB                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Speicher}                 & Kartenleser für \\Full SD & Micro SD & Kartenleser für Full SD & Micro SD  & Micro SD \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Anzahl der USB 2.0 Anschlüsse} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1}        & 2     & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{4}       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Ethernet}                      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{-}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{10 und 100 MBit}         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Pin}                      & 26        & 40           & 26                     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{40}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{GPIO-Pins}                     & 17                                           & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{26}        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{17}                                    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{26}                             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Weitere Schnittstellen}& \multicolumn{5}{c|}{1 x CSI, 1 x DSI, 1 x I$^{2}$C, 1 x I$^{2}$S}                       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Stromversorgung}               & \multicolumn{5}   {c|}{5,0 V; über einen Micro-USB-Anschluss (Micro-USB-B)}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\listoftables               % Tabellenverzeichnis
\listoffigures              % Abbildungsverzeichnis
\bibliography{Literatur}    % Sie benötigen einen *.bib-Datei

\appendix

\end{document}
```

I want to fit it to the width of a page. I had read a couple of possible solutions (in stackexchange too) I had tried with tabularx too but no one helps.

Comment: on a sidenote: why are you using bibtotoc twice?

Comment: I have included it twice accidentally

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can make the table fit inside the available text block if you want to display it in portrait mode, unless you choose a truly microscopic font size (which I wouldn't recommend you do). Instead, try to typeset the table in landscape mode, e.g., by using the `sidewaystable` environment (provided by the `rotating` package).

I wouldn't use bold-facing *and* underlining to create emphasis. Bold-facing alone should be more than enough for this task.

Incidentally, are the entries "1024 MB" and "26" in the table's final column misplaced? Similarly, should the cells `Full SD`, `Micro SD`, `Kartenleser für Full SD`, `Micro SD`, and `Micro SD` be shifted to the right by one or two columns?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt
DIVcalc,        % führt die Satzspiegelberechnung neu aus
twoside         % einseitiges Layout
twocolumn,      % zweispaltiger Satz
openany,        % Kapitel können auch auf linken Seiten beginnen
headsepline,    % Trennline zum Seitenkopf  
footsepline,    % Trennline zum Seitenfuß
chapterprefix,  % vor Kapitelüberschrift wird "Kapitel Nummer" gesetzt
appendixprefix, % Anhang wird "Anhang" vor die Überschrift gesetzt 
normalheadings, % Überschriften etwas kleiner (smallheadings)
idxtotoc,       % Index im Inhaltsverzeichnis
liststotoc,     % Abb.- und Tab.verzeichnis im Inhalt
bibtotoc,
bibtotoc
]
{scrbook}


\pagestyle{headings}    % lebender Kolumnentitel  

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{array}    % for '\extrarowheight' macro
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' environment

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example

\begin{sidewaystable}

    \small
    \captionsetup{font=small}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

    \caption{Eigenschaften des Raspberry Pi}
    \label{tab:EigenschaftendesRaspberryPitabelle}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Eigenschaften}}            &  \textbf{Modell A}  & \textbf{Modell A+} &         \textbf{Modell B} & \textbf{Modell B+} & \textbf{Raspberry Pi 2 Model B} \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Gesamtgrösse (in mm)} & Länge  & 93        & 70,4        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{93}                         \\ \cline{2-10} 
                                                                            & Breite & 63,5      & 57,2        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{63,5}                       \\ \cline{2-10} 
                                                                            & Höhe   & 17        & 12          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{20}                         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{SoC}                      & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Broadcom BCM2835}         & Broadcom BCM2836       \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{CPU}                  & Typ    & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{ARM1176JZF-S}             & ARM Cortex-A7          \\ \cline{2-10} 
                                                                            & Kern   & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{1}                        & 4                      \\ \cline{2-10} 
                                                                            & Takt   & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{700 MHz}                  & 900 MHz                \\ \cline{2-10} 
                                                                            & Architektur & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{ARMv6}               & ARMv7                  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Arbeitsspeicher}          & 256 MB & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{512 MB}          & 1024 MB                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Speicher}                 & Kartenleser für \\Full SD & Micro SD & Kartenleser für Full SD & Micro SD  & Micro SD \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Anzahl der USB 2.0 Anschlüsse} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1}        & 2     & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{4}       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Ethernet}                      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{-}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{10 und 100 MBit}         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Pin}                      & 26        & 40           & 26                     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{40}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{GPIO-Pins}                     & 17                                           & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{26}        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{17}                                    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{26}                             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Weitere Schnittstellen}& \multicolumn{5}{c|}{1 x CSI, 1 x DSI, 1 x I$^{2}$C, 1 x I$^{2}$S}                       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Stromversorgung}               & \multicolumn{5}   {c|}{5,0 V; über einen Micro-USB-Anschluss (Micro-USB-B)}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, posted after the OP mentioned in a comment that he/she would prefer to typeset the table in portrait mode and that the horizontal margins are 25mm: To get the table to fit in the text block in portrait mode, you may want think seriously about using a sans-serif font that's a lot more condensed than `Helvetica`. If you're free to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you could use any system font that's a condensed sans serif. For instance, working with `Myriad Pro Condensed` (available for free on my system -- MacOSX and MacTeX2015) produces the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
11pt
DIVcalc,        % führt die Satzspiegelberechnung neu aus
twoside         % einseitiges Layout
twocolumn,      % zweispaltiger Satz
openany,        % Kapitel können auch auf linken Seiten beginnen
headsepline,    % Trennline zum Seitenkopf  
footsepline,    % Trennline zum Seitenfuß
chapterprefix,  % vor Kapitelüberschrift wird "Kapitel Nummer" gesetzt
appendixprefix, % Anhang wird "Anhang" vor die Überschrift gesetzt 
normalheadings, % Überschriften etwas kleiner (smallheadings)
idxtotoc,       % Index im Inhaltsverzeichnis
liststotoc,     % Abb.- und Tab.verzeichnis im Inhalt
bibtotoc,
bibtotoc
]
{scrbook}


\pagestyle{headings}    % lebender Kolumnentitel  

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, hmargin=25mm, vmargin=3cm }

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
%\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Myriad Pro Condensed}[BoldFont = "Myriad Pro Bold Condensed"]

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{array}    % for '\extrarowheight' macro

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example

\begin{table}[ht!]

    \small
    \captionsetup{font=small}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}

\caption{Eigenschaften des Raspberry Pi}
\label{tab:EigenschaftendesRaspberryPitabelle}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Eigenschaften}} &  \textbf{Modell A}  
& \textbf{Modell A+} & \textbf{Modell B} & \textbf{Modell B+} 
& \textbf{Raspberry Pi 2 Model B} \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Gesamtgrösse (in mm)} & Länge  & 93 & 70,4 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{93} \\ 
\cline{2-10} 
& Breite & 63,5 & 57,2 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{63,5}\\ 
\cline{2-10} 
& Höhe   & 17 & 12 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{20}\\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{SoC} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Broadcom BCM2835}  & Broadcom BCM2836 \\ 
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{CPU}  & Typ    & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{ARM1176JZF-S} & ARM Cortex-A7 \\ 
\cline{2-10} 
& Kern   & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{1}          & 4 \\ 
\cline{2-10} 
& Takt   & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{700 MHz}    & 900 MHz \\ 
\cline{2-10} 
& Architektur & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{ARMv6} & ARMv7 \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Arbeitsspeicher} & 256 MB 
& \multicolumn{4}{c|}{512 MB} & 1024 MB \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Speicher} & Kartenleser für \\
Full SD & Micro SD & Kartenleser für Full SD & Micro SD  & Micro SD \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Anzahl der USB 2.0 Anschlüsse} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1} & 2 & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{4} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Ethernet} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{-}
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{10 und 100 MBit}\\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Pin} & 26 & 40 & 26 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{40}\\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{GPIO-Pins} & 17 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{26} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{17} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{26} \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Weitere Schnittstellen} 
& \multicolumn{5}{c|}{1 x CSI, 1 x DSI, 1 x I$^{2}$C, 1 x I$^{2}$S}\\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Stromversorgung} 
& \multicolumn{5}{c|}{5,0 V; über einen Micro-USB-Anschluss (Micro-USB-B)}\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: its dosent possible to fit it independent from the textwidth?

Comment: @Doan - How big `\textwidth` is in your document. 10cm? 30cm? Something inbetween? Please advise.

Comment: i have use following code to set the size:

   `\geometry{a4paper,
    left=25mm,
    right=25mm,    
    top=3cm,    
    bottom=3cm,
    }`

Comment: Also, have you considered the fact that the sans serif font you're working with -- Helvetica -- is not all that compact? To really save some space, and thus give yourself a better chance to typeset the table in portrait mode, can you switch from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX and use a font such as `Myriad Pro Condensed` of `Frutiger Condensed`?

Comment: @Doan - I've posted an addendum to show that if one can switch to a more "condensed" sans serif font, it is in fact possible to typeset the table in portrait mode.